# Reset all component's properties except excluded ones

Tags: vb.net, winforms, linq, typedescriptor

I have make a **Sub Procedure** which **gets** all the **properties** of a **component** into a list and then **resets** their values, **except** those I have declare as excluded.

```
Public Shared Sub ResetPropertiesByComponent(ByVal Component As Component, ByVal ExcludedProperties As String)
    Dim PropertyCollection As List(Of PropertyDescriptor) = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Component).OfType(Of PropertyDescriptor).
                                                                           Where(Function(item) item.Name <> ExcludedProperties).
                                                                           ToList()
    For Each _PropertyDescriptor As PropertyDescriptor In PropertyCollection
        If _PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue(Component) Then
            If _PropertyDescriptor.GetValue(Component) IsNot Nothing Then
                _PropertyDescriptor.ResetValue(_Control)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

And I use it like this: `Call ResetPropertiesByComponent(Me, "ClientSize")`.

My problem is when I try to make it **exclude more than one properties**. I changed my Sub Procedure like this:

```
Public Shared Sub ResetPropertiesByComponent(ByVal Component As Component, ByVal ExcludedProperties As String())
    Dim PropertyCollection As List(Of PropertyDescriptor) = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Component).OfType(Of PropertyDescriptor).
                                                                           Where(Function(item) item.Name IsNot ExcludedProperties).
                                                                           ToList()
    For Each _PropertyDescriptor As PropertyDescriptor In PropertyCollection
        If _PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue(Component) Then
            If _PropertyDescriptor.GetValue(Component) IsNot Nothing Then
                _PropertyDescriptor.ResetValue(_Control)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

From `ExcludedProperties As String`to `ExcludedProperties As String()`.

And from `Where(Function(item) item.Name <> ExcludedProperties)` to `Where(Function(item) item.Name IsNot ExcludedProperties)`. As `<>` is not defined for type `String()`.

And I use it like this: `Call ResetPropertiesByComponent(Me, {"ClientSize", "MinimumSize"})`.

I get no errors or something, but it does not work too!!! Any idea?

Comment: A big "thank you" to this guy who is "following" my questions for the sole purpose to downvote them and vote them to close!!! It would be really fair, if we could see who is he and also have a written reason for his actions.

Comment: I voted to close question as off topic as it was a debugging issue.

Comment: And why a question which is finally a debugging issue is off topic? Is there any rule for this or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use IEnumerable -> Contains

```
.Where(Function(item) Not ExcludedProperties.Contains(item.Name))
```

Have a quick read of the [IsNot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/isnot-operator) documentation. It is for comparing object references. It will not error because it is not supposed to, and always returns True because your string and string array won't be the same.